# Timescaledb compression, segmentby and chunking

Tags: timescaledb

Does the `segementby col` setting in timescaledb ensure that it will create a new chunk for each different value of col ? This is implied in the documentation but isn't explicitly stated anywhere.

For example, using the example from documentation will the following `segmentby deviceid`

```
time    device_id   cpu disk_io energy_consumption
[12:00:02, 12:00:01]    1   [88.2, 88.6]    [20, 25]    [0.8, 0.85]
[12:00:02, 12:00:01]    2   [300.5, 299.1]  [30, 40]    [0.9, 0.95]
```

Does this create 2 separate chunks for the given time range?
This is important as compressed chunks cannot be written/updated to, so if for the same time range a new device id data point appears later for ingesting, would this be an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A compressed hypertable is chunked in the same way as the original hypertable. The compression is applied to each chunk and it creates a compressed chunk for each original chunk.

`segmentby` specifies how to combine or group rows for compression. Each unique value of `segmentby` columns results in a record in the compressed chunk where values of all other columns are compressed together.

In the question example, there are two unique values in `segmentby` column `device_id`: `1` and `2`. Then the corresponding values in other columns are grouped together and compressed. So in the example, there are two rows for `device_id = 1` and two rows for `device_id = 2`. If all four original records were stored in the same chunk in the original hypertable, the two corresponding compressed records will be stored in one compressed chunk.

> This is important as compressed chunks cannot be written/updated to, so if for the same time range a new device id data point appears later for ingesting, would this be an issue?

It is not supported to do any changes to the original chunk, which was compressed. So inserting data with new `segmentby` value will fail with an error.

**UPDATE**: To update data in compressed chunks, e.g., backfill data, it is necessary to manually decompress chunks, update data and then compress data back as described in [decompression chunk documentation](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/compression#decompress-chunks).

Comment: If say `device_id = 3`  with the same time range was created later after the chunk was compressed, would be stored in a new chunk?

Comment: @nehz compressed chunks cannot be modified. In such case you will get an error. (I clearly missed this part of the question and will add to the answer)

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to make TSDB a bit more limiting when there is outstanding old data (e.g from offsite) to ingest

Comment: If I `create_hypertable` with `partitioning_column` on `device_id` wouldn't this create a chunk per unique `device_id` ?

Comment: @nehz Do you mean additional space dimension on `device_id`? Or do you want to use it as time dimension? If it is a time dimension then it will confuse TimescaleDB as the values will not move forward in "time". If it is an additional space dimension, then  it is necessary to specify the fixed number of partitions. Note that chunks are tables and bring overhead, so there is a tradeoff for the number of chunks and their size.

Comment: @nehz The only way to update data in compressed chunks is through manual decompression. I updated my answer. The limitation is understood and hopefully will be relaxed in future.

Comment: Yeah basically it is a backfill scenario which you linked to docs. I was hoping partitiong by `device_id` will allow me to backfill for new `device_id` tags but it does not work like that it seems. As it stands native compression will probably not work for me, but I will try ZFS compression for now